# Mobile Scrolling Bug

Tags: bug, mobile-web

When browsing on mobile, answers and their comments appear in their own container (`<div class="-summary answer">`).

This class is configured with `overflow: auto` and something within the container causes the content to be slightly taller, resulting in a rather annoying issue when trying to scroll via touch / drag

[image: mobile scrolling bug]

All I can tell is that it's something within the comments section,  possibly to do with the comment form toggle since the problem isn't present for deleted answers (no toggle present).

---

Update: The issue appears to be this element

[image: comment form toggle link]

It is an inline element with a vertical padding of `9px` top and bottom. Since it's inline, its container does not account for the padding-based height (`line-height` would be a better option than `padding` here). This creates a bottom margin which pushes out of the container height, creating a scrollable area.

Comment: Found the appropriate SE Meta post ~ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356917/answers-in-mobile-site-scroll-slightly

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as "not suitable for this site". The existence of a question on MSE doesn't make a question on MSO off-topic or otherwise unsuitable. If anything makes this unsuitable, it's the fact that the mobile website is long deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: @CodyGray if the mobile site is _"deprecated and no longer supported"_, why is it the default view on mobile devices?

Comment: Not a question I know the answer to. Other questions that I do not know the answer to: "If Windows 10 Pro is designed for business use, why does it come bundled with Candy Crush Saga?", "If 'people reached' is a meaningless and irrelevant metric, why is it prominently displayed on the user profile?", "If users aren't supposed to keep re-asking their question after the first one is closed, why does the blue banner tell them to do precisely that?", ...

Comment: @CodyGray What's your source on the mobile site being no longer supported? I've never seen any SE staff say that. And clearly they're making updates to it, or else this change wouldn't have occurred...